# Print only matching regex pattern from .groups()

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using `re` in python. I have multiple patterns compiled in `pattern`. When line matches, the match is captured in `match.group(1)` or `match.group(2)`, and so on.

```
pattern = re.compile('^(?:' + '|'.join(patterns) + ')')

for line in sys.stdin:
    match = pattern.search(line)
    if match:
        fout.write(match.group(1) + '\n')
```

In the code above, I am trying to print `group(1)`. But I don't know which `group` contains my match. How can I find out, and print only the matching group?

Comment: What do you mean? Your code does only print the matching group. If you want to know which pattern matched, why not test each one separately?

Comment: Either use `match.group()` to get the entirety of the matched string, or if you really only want a specific group, then match each regex pattern separately.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - but how can i test which one matched ? That's what I need to know.

Comment: ... *"test each one separately"*. To put it another way: if which one matched matters, why are you smashing them all together?